# How to connect CSS file with JSP view in Spring MVC App right?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, intellij-idea

I have some CRUD app that connected through hibernate with the database. There is one JSP file in views. Everything is configured in the config XML file. But CSS still doesn't work.

My app running on IntelliJ  IDEA 2019.1.2, MySql 8, Spring 5, Tomcat 9. I tried a few different ways to set up in JSP file path to CSS files. But the result always the same. Everything working, but without styles.

[servlet config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSJXB.png)

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPzF4.png)

[jsp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8hvS.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrQZm.png)

Comment: Post your code, not images of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the  [png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8hvS.png) you it seem you are using resourses instead of resources. Also verify in developer tool of your browser the name of resources folder. You can go to sources tab(chrome) or debugger(firefox) and check the folder structure.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! In location was "resources", but in mapping was "resourses". That's all the problem... Now working fine!